# Is Intrinsic camera matrix the same for the same type of smart phone?

Tags: iphone, computer-vision, augmented-reality, camera-calibration

I am developing an augmented reality APP, and need to calculate intrinsic camera parameters (i.e., focal length, distortion parameters) firstly. Since we targets at all smart phones. The stability of intrinsic camera matrix is very critical.

I know intrinsic camera matrix depends on the camera. Since the same type of smart phone uses the same type of camera, iss the intrinsic camera matrix the same for the same type of smart phone?

1) If it is the case. There should be a intrinsic parameters database for all types of smart phones, since such parameters are measured again and again. Does such a database exist?

2) If it is not the case, it means such intrinsic parameters are not the same for every smart phone. It is impossible to measure these parameters for every user's phone. The following question is how to deal with this problem since other APP developers also meet this problem.

Furthermore, as point it out in [Same intrinsic parameter for same camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827488/same-intrinsic-parameter-for-same-camera?rq=1), can we assume that parameters for the same type of phone, is the accuracy is acceptable for AR task.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't kow about such a database, but in blender, you have presets for intrinsic parameters corresponding to a few different cameras/smartphones.

Comment: Agree with Francesco,
If you would need high accuracy(pixel or even subpixel),
you would probably need a calibration procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the level of accuracy you need. If low, you can use whatever information the camera itself provides (focal length and device size, essentially), and assume a pinhole model.

For higher accuracy you need a procedure that allows you to refine the intrinsic on a particular device, starting from the presets. There are many ways of doing so, some more user-friendly than others.